# Using flutter/dart vscode shows "method isn't defined" when i check for a specific mixin before calling it

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, mixins

This is my first time messing with dart and i'm stuck with this silly error. I'm 90% confident that the error lies on the vscode part of it, because there aren't errors showing when running the app.

Maybe I'm approaching the problem in the wrong way, I simply want to call a mixin function in objects that implements the mixin. In java for example it would be required to cast the component variable, but I couldn't get cast to work in this situation.

#### Code

[image: code]

#### Error

> The method 'onPanUpdate' isn't defined for the class 'Component'.
>   Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'onPanUpdate'.

#### Source Code

[Repo link](https://github.com/guiquintelas/blue-box-flutter/blob/9e704eff77e44faecd1fc4d1df27aec10ff08144/lib/blue_box_game.dart#L21)

[Component class source](https://github.com/flame-engine/flame/blob/master/lib/components/component.dart)

Comment: There could be two scenarios, one like you said its a vscode thing. Some times restarting the IDE does the trick. Another scenario might be that vscode is right about complaining but because maybe the `if block ` is never reached while executing the app runs with no problems( so far ).

Comment: Can you give more details about the class `Component`?

Comment: Does running `flutter analyze` report any issues?

Comment: @Moqbel restarting vscode doesn't fix the error :/ the if block is been reached because I have some running logic there. I edited the question with source code links :)

Comment: @jamesdlin shows the same error. Today I can't even run the app, the same error pops up in the console as a compilation error :/

Comment: @GuilhermeFrota thanks for sharing the code. Its not clear where `this.components` comes from in the code though.

Comment: Try this

`for(var component in this.components){
  if(component is PanDetector){
    var tempComponent =  component as PanDetector;
    tempComponent.onPanUpdate(details);
  }
}`
I don't if you are allowed to cast to mixin to be honest.

Comment: @Moqbel thanks for the help man, this does the trick :) I had tried something similar but using the same `component` variable, but i guess once a variable in dart has a type it can't be changed, i don' know

Comment: @GuilhermeFrota glad to be of help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Maybe I'm approaching the problem in the wrong way, I simply want to call a mixin function in objects that implements the mixin. In java for example it would be required to cast the component variable, but I couldn't get cast to work in this situation.

For this to work it must be done with the following code:

```dart
for (var component in this.components) {
  if (component is PanDetector) {
    (component as PanDetector).onPanUpdate(details);
  }
}
```

Especial thanks to [@Moqbel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61533238/using-flutter-dart-vscode-shows-method-isnt-defined-when-i-check-for-a-specif?noredirect=1#comment108880351_61533238)